# KTables - KStreams ; Adding to KTable is not "kickstarting" the topology

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology that computes the number of times a particular IP address is seen and that by itself works great. Now I am trying to add exclusions, i.e. do not count for this IP address.

As of now, this topology is a KStream of messages (call it IP-stream) containing data + the IP Address and adding messages to this stream updates the counts, as expected.

Now I need to add exclusions which comes from another topic and those exclusions rarely changes, a few times a month.

The idea is to read from the exclusion topic, convert it to a KTable then I left join the IP-Stream to the KTable to exclude the IP's found in the IP-Stream. (Not sure that works yet)

My process (topology) is running and when I add an IP address to exclude to the KTable, I see in the StateStore generated by the left-join of KStream to KTable, the IP I added to the KTable but the recount of IPs is not happening.

The initial counts have already been computed and I would like to recompute them when there is a change in the KTable, is that possible? I expected a change to restart the computation.

Comment: KStream-Ktable joins are only triggered by changes to the KStream. This is because only the KTable is materialized in a state store. The content of the KStream is processed one message at a time, and once a message of the KStream has been processed it is no longer relevant. You could convert your resulting KTable back to a stream, and then filter out all counts that should be excluded.

Comment: I was looking into what you proposed but the issue being, that our exclusions are much smaller in size compared to the data to process, and the exclusions are something that changes a few times a month. 

Also, the keys are not the same. We have about 60 billions record monthly with a key that is not the IP (we do have it in the data) and our exclusion data is mapped with IP .

The reason I was thinking of using a table is to look up the data while filtering versus remapping 60 billion records

Comment: If you exclude an IP from counting, why do you need to re-count? Would this not just filter a certain row in your result table?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, The exclusion can happen any time during the count. Data comes in and we keep running totals and then we receive a list of exclusions, lets says mid month and we need to recompute all the values, excluding the IPs provided. Right now this is done (using hadoop clusters) where the data is reloaded from scratch , and this is really expensive time (6 hours or so) and dollar wise. My thought is to have the data preprocessed and we apply exclusions on that (versus from scratch). Other reports all also running off the preprocessed data).

Comment: Continued from above... So my idea is to have a process that reads from 2 streams, one stream has the preprocessed data the other , the exclusions (I thought of a table at first, but wouldn't work). The process (a node in the topology) would update the count if and when it receives an exclusion. I read elsewhere this also might not be possible , since  I would need to reprocess data from the preprocessed stream. Really stuck on this one.

Comment: If you only have one global count, but not know the count per IP, it's not possible to "exclude" on the fly, but you need to re-process from scratch. I guess, if you keep a count per IP, and if you are able to substract that count from the global count, it might be possible. But this goes way beyond what can be answered here...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.Reprocessing from "scratch" will be better than what we are doing now. The hadoop jobs starts way back, at the files and at least, here we will be able to work on "preprocessed data", saving many steps. I will explore your idea of substracting from the global counts.Thanks again